# Display picture in gridview column

Tags: c#, image, gridview

I have a bounded griview1 and I add it a Column as repositoryItemImageEdit1

Im trying to display a picture with the path string

```
      DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Card.CardView view = sender as DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Card.CardView;


 Image img= Image.FromFile("\\path");  view.SetRowCellValue(rowindex, view.Columns["photo"], img);
```

Comment: And what is the issue? What happens?

Comment: nothing happen the cells of that columns are empty